# CGI working directory (trying to load a template file)

Tags: apache, path, directory, cgi

I have a CGI-script which tries to load a template file. However, I get an error where the file location of the CGI-script itself is added to the path where I try to load the template:

```
let template_string = Jg_template.from_file "/home/d37433/templates/startpage.tmpl" in
```

Error:

```
file /home/d37433/public_html/cgi-bin//home/d37433/templates/startpage.tmpl not found
```

Is there an error in my Apache config? The same code worked on another machine of mine (unfortunately, I don't have access to it at the moment).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by programmatically change the working directory inside the CGI script.